# Ansible transform tasks

Tags: ansible

I have ansible task for copy some file to my servers

```
- name: Copy file 
  copy:
    src: files/prod
    dest: /etc/prod
```

but i want to do this regard of some extra positional parameter

for example if i
`ansible-playbook copy.yml dev` my task transform to

```
- name: Copy file
  copy:
    src: files/dev
    dest: /etc/dev
```

and
`ansible-playbook copy.yml prod`  my task transform to

```
- name: Copy file
  copy:
    src: files/prod
    dest: /etc/prod
```

any ways to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create variable e.g. *unit*

```yaml
shell> cat copy.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: "files/{{ unit }}"
        dest: "/etc/{{ unit }}"
```

and use it e.g.

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook copy.yml -e "unit=dev"
```